# How to capture debugging,warning and error messages?

Tags: python

I have setup logging as follows in my script, however it doesn't capture the `warning`,`debug` or when the script fails with an error like `TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

```
### Setup logging
log = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'clone.log')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-20s %(lineno)-5s  %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

fh = logging.FileHandler(log, 'w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Current log:

```
2018-02-01 10:44:20 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                61     
2018-02-01 10:44:24 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                130    INFO    : Updating milestone & category
2018-02-01 10:44:24 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                131    INFO    : 12
2018-02-01 10:44:24 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                132    INFO    : None
2018-02-01 10:44:24 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                61     INFO    : Logging into radar
2018-02-01 10:44:24 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                68     INFO    : Getting original Radar details
2018-02-01 10:44:28 cloneradar_keyword.py clone                81     INFO    : Creating clone
```

NOT CAPTURING:

```
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        _login               98     DEBUG   : new_time : 1517510668.06
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        _login               99     DEBUG   : Difference : 3.45849394798
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        _login               132    DEBUG   : Cookie is still valid...
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        CreateCloneProblem   298    INFO    : {"component":{"name":"Resource Meter","version":"Lanai"},"originatorOfClone": true,"reason":"Cloning for automation"}
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        CreateCloneProblem   302    WARNING : Error: Unable to get data. Server came back with:
2018-02-01 10:44:28 radar.py        CreateCloneProblem   303    WARNING : {"message":"The component you've selected is closed. There is no follow-on component. A problem cannot be saved to a closed component with no follow-on. Please select a different component.","help":"View documentation at http://radar.apple.com/","title":"Problem Update Failed","status":"400 Bad Request"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cloneradar_keyword.py", line 181, in <module>
    cloneID = clone(user, id)
  File "./cloneradar_keyword.py", line 88, in clone
    newRadarID = newRadar['id']
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Is what you are showing as "current log" the result of `ch` or of `fh`? And where does the output under "NOT CAPTURING" appear?

Comment: What if you change `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to `logger.setLevel(10)` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR - changing `logger.setLevel(10)` didn't make any difference

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I only see `INFO` in the clone.log,so probably `ch` and the "NOT CAPTURING" is on the console

Comment: The docs say >**Note** Integer levels should be used when e.g. setting levels on instances of Logger and handlers. Not sure if that's the cause though.